# How to create a xamarin apple watch modal send data back

Tags: xamarin, modal-dialog, segue, apple-watch

This seems like it should be straight forward, but I'm having trouble solving it.

I will simplify the problem to get to the heart of the question.

I am building a Xamarin Watch OS 3 app.  I have an InterfaceController1 and an InterfaceController2 on my storyboard.  I added a button to InterfaceController1 and created a segue to InterfaceController2.  I made it a modal.

On InterfaceController2, I have Picker list.  I want to choose an item, close the modal InterfaceController2 (which automatically sends me back to InterfaceController1), and have that data (whatever I picked from the list)  available in InterfaceController1.

This seems very basic...why else would you pop up a modal if not to make a selection and return back to the main scene.  But I can't seem to figure it out.  I see examples for iPhone apps, but they don't seem to apply for Apple Watch apps.  Unless I am misunderstanding something.